# jQuery function (scroll to anchor) with an if/else statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

so I'm reaally new to Javascript/jQuery trying to teach myself and now I don't understand why something won't work.

Basically I have a menu on my website, and when a link is clicked I want it to scroll down to an anchor. Which works really good.

But now I also want the following: When the window width is less than 360px I want the scrolling to stop 80px above the anchor.

Now this works just fine:

```
jQuery(function() {

 jQuery('.moduletable_resmenu a').click(function(){ 
     jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 1000);
     return false;
  });
});
```

And this aswell:

```
jQuery(function() {

 jQuery('.moduletable_resmenu a').click(function(){ 
     jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).offset().top-80
     }, 1000);
     return false;
  });
});
```

But when I try to combine these and include an if/else statement, it doesn't work:

```
jQuery(function() {

 jQuery('.moduletable_resmenu a').click(function(){ 
  if ($(window).width() < 360){  
     jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).offset().top-80
     }, 1000);
     return false;
  } 
  else {
     jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 1000);
     return false;
  }
 });
});
```

I probably just don't have enough understanding Javascript/jquery, can someone help me and tell me what I need to do in order to get this working?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code, could be the html maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/exed7x0q/ what you have works

Comment: please change your code to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and use the [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)  function, in that case is easier for us to reproduce the probelm.

Comment: @Huangism I use Joomla 3.8.2 as CMS if that changes anything, I don't know - but since everything works without the if-statement I don't know what should be wrong

Comment: @kalu do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: oh yes i do i didn't notice it says "TypeError: $ is not a function" on the line where my if-statement starts!

Comment: @kalu replace `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: @Huangism Thank you a lot I realized that too :) now it finally works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after checking the console, the error showed: "TypeError: $ is not a function" - Apparently this is a Joomla specific thing that by default if you enqueue jQuery in Joomla "jQuery" is used instead of "$"- I changed my code to

```
jQuery(function() {

 jQuery('.moduletable_resmenu a').click(function(){ 
// $ to jQuery 
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 360){  
     jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).offset().top-80
     }, 1000);
     return false;
  } 
  else {
     jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 1000);
     return false;
  }
 });
});
```

And now it works!